# How do I ensure that the function executes before data passes in angular2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to first run the function getCompletedExams on the service and return all the data to enrolled_exams array but What is happening is first null values are set into the enrolled_exam and then the getCompletedExams runs. I know that Angular is asynchronous so this could happen but I don't know how to solve it. the code is attached here.

```
private setMyEnrolledExams() {

this.homeTabService.getCompletedExams(this.studentId).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
  this.enrolled_exams = result["response"];
  console.log("this "+this.enrolled_exams);
  this.setPage(1);
});}
```

I tried something like this:

```
  private setEnrolledExams()
  {
    this.homeTabService.getCompletedExams(this.studentId).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
      this.enrolled_array = result["response"];
      console.log("this "+this.enrolled_exams);
       this.setPage(1);
    });
  }
private setMyEnrolledExams() {


  this.enrolled_exams = this.enrolled_array;

}
```

But it still doing the same thing the function executes first and prints the null value and then the array is loaded with the real values.

Comment: Have you checked if your `result['response']` returning `null` ? Since `this.enrolled_exams` is an array, why are you concatenating it with a string in the `console.log("this "+this.enrolled_exams)` ?

Comment: It is returning an array of object that I want and "this" I added for debugging purpose.

Comment: If the `result['response']` is returning an array of objects then there should be no problem since you are assigning it to `this.enrolled_exams`.

Comment: At first it is returning null but and assigns null to enrolled_exams and then it loads the data

Comment: Can you post full code of service? and whether `setMyEnrolledExams` and `setEnrolledExams` are both same?

Comment: @kingforever, in which part of the code does the data gets loaded properly ? Is it the UI template code where you are not getting the data and instead getting `null` ?

Comment: Add the sevice function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the data using following code:

```
private setMyEnrolledExams() {

if(this.homeTabService.getCompletedExams(this.studentId).subscribe(result=>{
    if(this.enrolled_exams != null )
    {
      this.enrolled_exams = result["response"];
      this.setPage(1);

    }

  }))
{

}
}
```